# GCP ssh Laravel Application down frequently

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just recently register for Google Cloud.

Using the SSH function, I install laravel and run it using "sudo php artisan serve --host=10.134.0.2 --port=80"

but the website will go down a few minutes after.

Is the command only run when I am log in to the ssh?

So how do I want my Laravel website to stay up?

Comment: 1) Never run PHP/Laravel with sudo. 2) Check the logs for error messages to know why the site is going down.

Comment: If I did not use sudo I get an error permission denied. Only with sudo my web is up, but temporarily

Comment: Port 80 is privileged. Use a web server such as Nginx or Apache to proxy PHP running on a different port above 1024. Again, never use sudo to run PHP/Laravel on a public network interface.

Comment: May I know the reason not to run sudo, I am new, so can you explain. Thank You

Comment: Google search. Only use hardened web servers on public interfaces.